# Determining return address of function on ARM Cortex-M series

Tags: c, assembly, arm, memory-address, keil

I want to determine the return address of a function in Keil. I opened diassembly section at debugging mode in Keil uvision. What is shown is some assembly code like this:

[image]

My intention is to inject a simple binary code to microcontroller via using buffer overflow at microcontroller.[see: Buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow)
I want to determine the return address of "test" function . Is it a must to know how to read assembly code or are there any trick to find the return address?

I am newbie to assembly.

Comment: On ARM, the return _value_ will be in `r0` and the address where the function will return will be saved in `lr` (look for a `bx lr` or `pop {pc}` instruction).

Comment: You definitely need to know a minimum of assembly for the processor you use. BTW why do you need to know the return address? What are you going to do with it?

Comment: well , I am studying on hardware security. I am trying to do code injection by benefiting from buffer overflow at microcontrollers.

Comment: I'm afraid that on ARM in such a simple function you can't overwrite the return address of the called function because it is in the register LR(R14), mostly.

Comment: @emreiris so put some effort when you ask quiestion. The port subject does not make any sense.

Comment: @thebusybee That is why It is called code injection. If data size is not controlled then someone can cause overflow and change return address of function.

Comment: Yes, I know. And because the return address in *not* in the stack, you can't overflow another local variable on the stack in order to change it.

Comment: @thebusybee: Note that the function does push `lr` and pop it back into `pc` (directly because it doesn't need bx for thumb interworking), so you could overwrite it in stack memory.

Comment: Oh, right, the function is not simple enough. ;-) I was misled by the value in LR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a function is called, R14 will be overwritten with the address following the call ("BL" or "BLX") instruction.  If that function doesn't call any other functions, R14 will *often* be left holding the return address for its duration.  Further, if the function tail-calls another function, the tail call may be replaced with a branch ("B" or "BX"), with R14 holding the return address of the original caller.  If a function makes a non-tail call to another function, it will be necessary to save R14 "somewhere" (typically the stack, but possibly to another previously-used caller-saved register) at some time before that, and retrieve that value from the stack at some later time, but if optimizations are enabled the location where R14 is saved will generally be unpredictable.

Some compilers may have a mode that would stack things consistently enough to be usable, but code will be very compiler-dependent.  The technique most likely to be successful may be to do something like:

```
extern int getStackAddress(uint8_t **addr);  // Always returns zero
void myFunction(...whavever...)
{
  uint8_t *returnAddress;
  if (getStackAddress(&returnAddress)) return; // Put this first.
}
```

where the `getStackAddress` would be a machine-code function that stores R14 to the address in R0, loads R0 with zero, and then branches to R14.  There are relatively few code sequences that would be likely to follow that, and if a code examines instructions at the address stored in `returnAddress` and recognizes one of these code sequences, it would know that the return address for `myFunction` is stored in a spot appropriate for the sequence in question.  For example, if it sees:

```
    test r0,r0
    be ...
    pop {r0,pc}
```

It would know that the caller's address is second on the stack.  Likewise if it sees:

```
    cmp r0,#0
    bne somewhere:
somewhere: ; Compute address based on lower byte of bne
    pop {r0,r1,r2,r4,r5,pc}
```

then it would know that the caller's address is sixth.

There are a few instructons compilers could use to test a register against zero, and some compilers might use `be` while others use `bne`, but for the code above compilers would be likely to use the above pattern, and so counting how many bits are set in the `pop` instruction would reveal the whereabouts of the return address on the stack.  One wouldn't know until runtime whether this test would actually work, but in cases where it claims to identify the return address it should actually be correct.

Answer (score 3):

`R14` or in other name `LR` hold the return address. On the left you can see it in the picture. It is `0x08000287`.

Comment: in this case the return address was pushed on the stack and will be used from the stack.  on the highlighted line at that time lr in your register window is that address as answered here, but the BL instruction will change the contents of LR.  If your goal is to change the return address then you need to modify the stack for this specific piece of code.  confused as to what your goal is, simply to understand what the address is (note the actual address is 0x080000287&0xFFFFFFFE), or something related to the return?

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the answers in the Cortex-M documentation

http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0337h/Chdedegj.html

[image]